# Household_objects_database new entries

Tags: ros, object-recognition, object-manipulation, household-objects-database

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know about the possibility to add objects to the household_objects_database once it is downloaded and run on local machine.
Is it possible for example using rein or other tools from the object_recognition stack?

Thank you so much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9421/household_objects_database-new-entries/) by [Lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/293/lorenzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/object_manipulation/trunk/household_objects_database/src/mesh_loader.cpp is a good starting place for this task.

Try using this as a template to move forward.

---

Originally posted by [ethanrublee](https://answers.ros.org/users/200/ethanrublee/) with karma: 225 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After upgrading to diamondback, also take a look at the insert_model.cpp node in the household_objects_database package. This allows you to add new object models (meshes) to the database. It is somewhat crude and not well parameterized, but should have all the info needed.

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1